# Replacing emoji in string results in odd characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, encoding

I have this string: `s = '☀️✈️✈️вьетнам'`

I want to remove emoji from it.

So I'm doing:

```
import re
emoji_re = re.compile(u'['
    u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
    u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
    u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]+', 
    re.UNICODE)
new = emoji_re.sub(r'', s)
```

Which gives me an odd result that I'm showing as a screenshot because I wasn't able to copy and paste it here.

[image]

Strangely you can see that "print" show me the correct result. Why is this happening?

Comment: For me, [another odd thing](https://i.imgur.com/fXWLY7P.png) is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a shot at ideone with this code:

```
import re

s = '☀️✈️✈'
emoji_re = re.compile(u'['
    u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
    u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
    u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]+', 
    re.UNICODE)
new = emoji_re.sub(r'', s)
print(new)
```

And the output was, well, kind of empty. Only kind of because I then added:

```
print(len(new))
```

Which output:

> 2

I was glad to see that we're dealing with unprintable char and that's why you can't paste it here. Encoding the string to utf-8:

```
print(new.encode("utf-8"))
```

Outputs

> b'\xef\xb8\x8f\xef\xb8\x8f'

---

Looking at [unicodelookup](http://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F%E2%9C%88%EF%B8%8F%E2%9C%88/1) it seems that the regex misses this char:

```
 variation selector-16  0xFE0F
```